# How to pass data from a FileMaker field to an Applescript

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I need to delete a file off of my Cincinnati Laser from FileMaker. It gets it there via a FMScript that export field contents of a container to this location. So I know the file name and the path its all built in a calculation field on that record. But I don't know how to get that info into an Applescript using the FM12 "Perform AppleScript" script step
When I hard code the path and file name (Shown Below) it works.

```
set xpath to "Titanium Brain:Users:smartin:Desktop:Laser:1512-clr-c.cnc"
tell application "Finder"
   delete file xpath
end tell
```

When I try to pass the field contents (Shown Below) it doesn't work.

```
set xpath to Laser::gCNCPath
tell application "Finder"
   delete file xpath
end tell
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you log what value xpath is in the second script? Try this as the second line (without quotes): 'display dialog (xpath as string)'. My hunch is it's to do with getting that xpath value into Applescript correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Perform AppleScript with calculations is always the managing of quotes and returns. Putting exactly the following into the 'Calculated Applescript' box of the 'Perform Applescript' script step should work for you:

```
"set xpath to " & Quote ( Laser::gCNCPath ) & ¶ &
"tell application \"Finder\"¶" &
   "delete file xpath¶" &
"end tell"
```

Honestly, though, the whole thing gets pretty ugly pretty quickly. If you have security locked down appropriately, I'd be more inclined to put the whole script into the Laser::gCNCPath field

```
set xpath to "Titanium Brain:Users:smartin:Desktop:Laser:1512-clr-c.cnc"
tell application "Finder"
    delete file xpath
end tell
```

And then, for the Perform Applescript, you only need to call the field:

```
Laser::gCNCPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've needed to pass information from FileMaker to AppleScript (and I'll admit, it's been a while since I've done so), I've used the Native AppleScript field in the Perform AppleScript dialog box and used a global field to store the "parameter" that AppleScript needs and used AppleScript to pull that information.

```
set xpath to cell "gCNCPath" of layout "Laser" of current file -- double check this syntax, I'm working from memory
tell app "Finder" to delete file xpath
```